# set print area to fit in after selected

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on making an invoice for a company with excel

So this invoice is based on changeable number of rows 
what I am trying to do is to select the print area based whatever the invoice came to and then make fit to the print page set up

I was able to do the first successfully but am having a hard time making that selection fit the print page afterward

here is my code

```
Sub BBPRINT_AREA()
    Range("AR148:AW239").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$AR$148:$AW$239"
    ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code can be used to select the range to print.

Note that the Paper Size is set to A4 and  Print Area is fit to one page. You can change both these properties in Page Setup once the macro is run and print preview is opened. The macro will not stop unless you exit print preview.

```
Sub SelectPrintArea()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim SelectPrint As Range
Set SelectPrint = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)

With ws.PageSetup
 .PrintArea = SelectPrint.Address
 .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
 .Zoom = False
 .FitToPagesTall = 1
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With

ws.PrintPreview

End Sub
```